# Absolute difference between a vector and a number in R

Tags: r, vector

I'm new to R and I would be very grateful for an answer to my question:

I've got a vector: `c(9, 11, 2, 6, 10)` and the number `4` (or a vector `c(4)`)

I want to generate a vector with the absolute difference between the first and the second one, which should look like this: `c(5, 7, 2, 2, 6)`

How do I do this? I can't get it to work with `diff()`, even after reading through the help (`?diff()`).

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c(9, 11, 2, 6, 10)
abs(x - 4)
#[1] 5 7 2 2 6
```

`abs` finds the absolute value of a vector. '4' will be recycled when subtracted from `x`. If you have multiple values to be subtracted, they will also be recycled with a warning unless they are the same length as `x`.

You ran into problems with `diff` because it isn't designed for scalar subtraction (what you are attempting). It is better suited to finding the difference *within* a vector.

Comment: Yeah, `diff` is named after the difference operator http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ForwardDifference.html